# How to catch the specific page template in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Here is a screenshot:

[image: See the screenshot]

I want to catch a specific page template and show meta box according the specific page template. I have tried to with it:

```
$pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
```

but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to *`functions.php`*:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'var_template_include', 1000);
function var_template_include($t) {
    $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] = basename($t);
    return $t;
}
    
function get_current_template() {
    if (isset($GLOBALS['current_theme_template'])) {
        return $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You'll then be able to do the following:

```
$pageTemplate = get_current_template();
```

Comment: Yes, it is help for catch current page template. when I will stay  in this page. but I want to catch my create page template and template filename and I wan to showing meta box according a specific template in post
see once the screenshot
https://prnt.sc/kvnDOZmLcZ-6
when user will select a specific page then showing be specific meta box for those page in the post

Comment: In that case I would recommend trying the plugin 'Advanced Custom Fields' (ACF), It will allow you to create editor UI elements depending on the type of content being edited.

Comment: Yes I know, but ACT is going to paid now , and price is very high for me. so I am finding other Options of ACF